# Pause to run third-party add-on

Tags: excel, vba

I broke a macro into 2 parts so that it could pause and use a third-party add-on to look up stock symbol descriptions. Some tickers don't have descriptions and the add-on returns "NTFND" if this is the case. I can find an alternate description for those securities but I need the formulas from the add-on to run to identify them. This works if I run Step1 and then Step2 separately.

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call Step1 'enters info from holdings sheet including ticker symbols

Application.Calculate

Call Step2 'fixes all the "Not Found" descriptions

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I tried the calculate function but it doesn't seem to calculate for the third-party add-on formulas. Is there another way I can have my Macro pause until the description formulas have run?

I just tried

`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))`

and

`If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then 
DoEvents 
End If`

Neither worked.

Comment: Application.Wait is not likely to work here, because it literally makes the application idle, as far as I know. Look in to using the WinAPI Sleep function, or calling step 2 from an `Application.OnTime` to *schedule* the second step to run at some future time (e.g., 5 seconds from now, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.Wait will indeed pause (for 5 sec in this case) until the next line of code being execute.

This might be what you are looking for:

[cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. This took a bit to figure out but its working.